# "break" in line when drawing with lineTo

Tags: javascript, canvas

This is my first time working with Canvas in Javascript. I'm trying to draw lines, pretty much. Here's what I'm getting in some of the lines (image below). Sometimes the line appears correct, but most of the time like this. As you can see there's a little break in the line where it appears darker. I'm trying to figure out the cause of this but no luck.

[image]

Here's my code. It's not very clean as it's still in development:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var Point = function(x, y) {
    this.startX = x;
    this.startY = y;
};
var Interval = function(x, y) {
    this.jumpX = x;
    this.jumpY = y;
};


var points = [
    [
        new Point(340, 130), // point start
        new Point(220, 130), // end first line
        new Point(220, 70), // end second line
        new Interval(-10, -10),
    ],
    [
        new Point(560, 80), // point start
        new Point(660, 80), // end first line
        new Point(660, 20), // end second line
        new Interval(10, -10),
    ],
    [
        new Point(620, 230), // point start
        new Point(770, 230), // end first line
        new Point(770, 150), // end second line
        new Interval(10, -10),
    ],
    [
        new Point(620, 230), // point start
        new Point(770, 230), // end first line
        new Point(770, 150), // end second line
        new Interval(10, -10),
    ],
];

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#DFC270";

var func = function(points, text, j1, j2) {
    var startX = points[0].startX,
        startY = points[0].startY,
        tempX = startX,
        tempY = startY,
        line1X = points[1].startX,
        line1Y = points[1].startY,
        line2X = points[2].startX,
        line2Y = points[2].startY;
   ctx.lineWidth = 1; 
   ctx.beginPath();
    var inter = function() {
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);

        // console.log(tempY + j1);
        if (tempY == line1Y && tempX  == line1X) {

            if (startX !== line2X) {
                startX += j2;
            }

            if (startY !== line2Y) {
                startY += j2;
            }

            if (startY == line2Y && startX == line2X) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                ctx.arc(startX, startY-j2, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#DFC270";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
                clearInterval(inter);
                return;
            }

        } else {
            if (startX !== line1X && tempX !== line1X) {
                startX += j1;
                tempX = startX;
            }

            if (startY !== line1Y && tempY !== line1Y) {
                startY += j1;
                tempY = startY;
            }
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(inter);
        ctx.lineTo(startX, startY);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(inter);
};

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    var interval = points[i][points[i].length-1];
    func(points[i], 'test', interval.jumpX, interval.jumpY);
};
```

Here's a fiddle I was able to recreate it on too

https://jsfiddle.net/e9vLoken/

Comment: Not the problem, but `clearInterval(inter);` isn't doing anything.

Comment: yeah i was using an interval previously, and switch to using `requestAnimationFrame`. Code is still in development.

Comment: I think at least part of the problem is that the `for` loop at the bottom. You're starting off four separate calls to `func()`, each of which then starts its own asynchronous process with `requestAnimationFrame()`, so then you have four animations going at once all using the same `ctx` variable.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too, but the same problem happens even if I only draw that one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to calling `beginPath()` twice, remove the extra method call under your if-statement:

```
var func = function(points, text, j1, j2) {
    ...
    ctx.beginPath(); // <-- Already called here
    ...
    var inter = function() {
        if (startY == line2Y && startX == line2X) {
            //ctx.beginPath(); <-- Remove this
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you never completed the final path stroke when the point where the circle is to be drawn.

at line 68 call the stroke function like this

```
    if (startY == line2Y && startX == line2X ) {
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.arc(startX, startY-j2, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#DFC270";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        clearInterval(inter);
        return;
```

Comment: yeah this didn't do anything.